# Can I use family share to send Css textures to brother's Gmod?

Tags: garrys-mod

My brother and I both own a copy of Gmod. However, only I own Css. Can I use the family share function to let him download counter strike and use the textured for Gmod?

Answer (score 1):

If you both play the game on the same computer the textures will be installed and copied over anyway. However if not you could go to [this website](http://kajar9.wix.com/cscheater2) go to the garrycontent page and scroll down to the part where it says Source Textures or something like that and add it to your

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steamapps\Common\Garry's Mod\addons

This will install the textures for you no matter what :D

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not help you in any scenario, but there are multiple CSS Textures already in the Steam Workshop of Garry's Mod: https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=4000

They are freely downloadable.

I didn't find much if family sharing would fix the problem, but I would give it a try since you own it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to own CSS to get the textures for Garry's Mod! Most people I would say don't own CSS :p It's also legal so no Issues there.

Link: [GMOD Textures](https://fragboss.com/gmod-textures-fix-css-textures/)

Literally only takes a couple minutes. That page has a video tutorial and the download links.